# python 3.5 TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python, list, mode

```
listg = [1,2,3,4,4,5,2]


modeval = [0]
modetimes = [0]

for i in range(len(listg)):
    count = listg.count(listg(i))
    if count > modetimes[0]:
        modeval = [listg(i)]
        count = [modeval]

    elif count == modetimes[0]:
        if listg in modeval:
            modeval.remove[listg(i)]
    modeval.append[listg(i)]

mode = modeval

print (mode)
```

I'm trying to find the mode of the list without using lambdas or the mode function but whenever I use the round brackets in the

```
count = listg.count(listg(i))
```

and the

```
modeval = [list(i)]
```

I get the TypeError: 'list' object is not callable. I tried turning the square brackets around the i into round ones but when I do the number that prints is the last in the list.

Comment: I just reread you question after posting my answer, and it seems like you tried using square brackets before, and it didn't work? What are you expecting `listg.count(listg(i))` to return the first time through the loop in your example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to index with brackets: change `listg(i)` to `listg[i]`. Parentheses are for function/method calls as the traceback suggests.

Also, I am a bit confused about what you are trying to accomplish, but I think it is generally considered a Python anti-pattern to use `for i in range(len(listg)):` in cases like this. Instead of using indexes, you can create ["beautiful, idiomatic Python"](https://gist.github.com/JeffPaine/6213790#looping-over-a-collection) by looping through the values in the list directly:

```
for i in listg:
    count = listg.count(i)
    if count > modetimes[0]:
        modeval = [i]
        count = [modeval]

...
```

Here `i` will be an actual element from `listg`, instead of an index used to retrieve the element.

Also note that assigning to a single object in square brackets, e.g., `modeval = [0]`, will give you a one-item list. If that is what you want then fine, but if that is not your intention, it may lead to confusing results.